# How to integrate with the jQuery Mobile framework?

Tags: 7, theming

I saw that Wordpress integrates a special plugin to transform Wordpress themes in mobile themes with an integration of the jQuery Mobile framework.

Is it possible to make for Drupal 7? Exist a module that can change or integrate with jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are currently people working on an integration of jQuery Mobile and Drupal.

Take a look at the [jQuery Mobile module](http://drupal.org/project/jquerymobile) and the [jQM Theme](http://drupal.org/project/jqm).  They are both currently only in dev, but I don't think there is much else out there yet.  If you prefer you could always do the integration yourself and use the basic [Mobile](http://drupal.org/project/mobile) theme.

The creators of this module and theme also have a video from Drupalcon Chicago that was very interesting: [Drupal on the go with jQuery Mobile](http://chicago2011.drupal.org/sessions/drupal-go-jquery-mobile)

Comment: Thanks for your response, i want to know if the browser automatically choose which theme showing to the user ....

Comment: I'm not sure if the module or theme does (or would do) that, but you can programmatically change the theme using your own logic if you want: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/139/correct-way-to-change-the-active-drupal-theme-programmatically

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [jQuery Mobile UI](http://drupal.org/project/jquerymobile_ui) module 
which has been created by Jason Savio. I attended his presentation on this module at DrupalCamp Boston and totally loved it. It is currently only for Drupal 6 but surely if you reach out to him, he may be able to provide more input on it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with jQuery Mobile integration for Drupal is that Drupal is much more complex than WordPress. A blog theme only need a frontpage with a listing of latest entries and individual pages, so it's quite easy to make a jQuery Mobile (or any mobile) theme for WP. Drupal sites have a higher complexity. Currently there is no out of the box solution to convert your Drupal sites to a jQuery Mobile site. You need to customize your blocks, build some simple Views for your mobile theme.